# If vs Case statements

Tags: performance, conditional-statements

Are there any performance differences between using if-else and case statements when handling multiple conditions?

Which is preferred?

Comment: This is very much language-dependent  switch/case statements work differently in different languages - for example, in some languages you can switch aon string, in others you cannot.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the one that's most readable in the given context.

Comment: thanks to all of you guys answers are very helpful about using if and case statements

Comment: Although i would agree - This didn't really answer the question. The question was about performance benefits.

Comment: The question was reworded after this answer, shifting emphasis quite a lot.

Answer (score 26):

In some languages, like C, `switch` may possibly be faster because it's usually implemented with a [jump table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_table). Modern compilers sometimes are smart enough to use one for several `if`s as well, though.

And anyway it probably won't matter, micro optimizations are (almost) never useful.

Answer (score 7):

When you have more than one ifelse, I recommend switch/select. Then again, it doesn't always work.

Suppose you something like that (not recommended but for example only)

```
If a > 0 and b > 0 then

' blabla
ElseIf b = -5 then

' blabla2
ElseIf a = -3 and b = 6 then

End If
```

Using a switch/select is NOT the way to go. However, when querying for a specific value for a variable like this

```
select case a

        case 1:
           ' blabla
        case 2:
           ' blabla2
        case 3:
           ' blabla3
        case 4:
           ' blabla4
        case else:
end select
```

In those case, I highly recommend it because it is more readable for other people.

Answer (score 5):

Some programming languages restrict when you can use `switch`/`case` statements.  For example, in many C-like languages the `case` values must be constant integers known at compile time.

Performance characteristics *may* differ between the two techniques, but you're unlikely to be able to predict in advance what they are.  If performance is really critical for this code in your application, make sure you **profile** both approaches before deciding, as the answers may surprise you.

Normally, performance differences will be negligible, and you should therefore choose the **most readable, understandable and maintainable** code, as you should in pretty much any other programming situation.

Answer (score 4):

`case` or `switch` statements are really just special cases of "if .. elseif..." structures that you can use when the same object is being compared to a different simple value in every branch, and that is all that is being done. The nice thing about using them is that most compilers can implement them as jump tables, so effectively the entire 200 (or however many) branch checks can be implemented as a single table indexing operation, and a jump.

For that reason, you'd want to use a `case` statement when you

1. *can* and
2. have a fairly large number of branches.

The larger the number of "elseif"s, the more attractive a `case` statement is.

Answer (score 3):

Case statements are generally preferred for readability and are generally faster if there is any speed difference, but this does not apply to every possible environment.

You could probably write a test that shows which is faster for your environment, but be careful with caching and compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

I will add to some of the answers here.  This is not a performance question, and if you are really concerned about performance... write a test and see which is faster.

However, this should be a question about which is proper to use, not which is better.  If you have multiple if/else statements then do yourself a favor and use a case statement.  If it is a simple if/else then use an if/else.  You'll thank yourself later.